# How to get changed line numbers of a perforce change list from C#/P4.net code

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am working on a perforce client plug-in and need help to get the changed line numbers. I have been able to get the change list and all the files are available locally.

Since it is a custom convenience tool, I can't ask for passwords for this operation.

I tried the approach to run P4Command with "Diff" command but it fails with exception "P4Command requires a P4Server". Creating a P4Server object needs user password. I was using following constructor.

public [P4Command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/M_Perforce_P4_P4Server__ctor.htm)(
    Repository repository,
    string command,
    bool taggedOutput,
    params string[] arguments
)

Is there any other approach available to solve this problem? Thanks!